# nm-applet missing after installing Ubuntu under virtualbox

Tags: network-manager

After installing Ubuntu under VirtualBox the nm-applet is missing.

I already tried to restart the applet but nothing has happened. Any suggestions?

```
$ kill nm-applet 
bash: kill: nm-applet: arguments must be process or job IDs 
$ kill 2649 
$ sudo nm-applet 


** (nm-applet:2740): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files 
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area 

** (nm-applet:2740): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files 
** Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon 

(nm-applet:2740): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_scale_simple: assertion `dest_width > 0' failed 
** Message: Starting applet secret agent because GNOME Shell disappeared 

** (nm-applet:2740): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

I already removed the `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` packages and reinstalled. Additionally I installed the package `network-manager-dpg` but the terminal apparently doesn't know the package `network-manager`. Synaptic tells me that both `network-manager` and `network-manager-gnome` are installed correctly.

There's just a problem with `network-manager-dbg` which I successfully reinstalled using the terminal but the error is still there. I can't upgrade the broken package via Internet since the connection doesn't work without the network-manager.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/network-manager-dbg_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 197394 files and directories currently installed.) 
Preparing to replace network-manager-dbg 0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3 (using .../network-manager-dbg_0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb) ... 
Unpacking replacement network-manager-dbg ... 
Setting up network-manager-dbg (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3) ... 
$ sudo service Network-manager start 
Network-manager: unrecognized service 
$ >

$ sudo service network-manager start 
[sudo] password for jonas: 
network-manager start/running, process 2471 
$ nm-applet 

** (nm-applet:2517): WARNING **: Could not initialize NMClient /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager: The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files 
** Message: applet now removed from the notification area 

** (nm-applet:2517): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files 
** Message: Starting applet secret agent because GNOME Shell disappeared 

** (nm-applet:2517): WARNING **: Failed to register as an agent: (2) The name org.freedesktop.NetworkManager was not provided by any .service files 
^C** Message: PID 0 (we are 2517) sent signal 2, shutting down... >
```

Comment: The service name is network-manager not Network-manager (doesn't use capital letters).

Comment: thanks for your response. i updated my post again. still the same problem as in the first place ... no nm-applet ...

Comment: Now I', lost. Maybe a it's a DBUS issue, but I'm out of ideas right now.

Comment: too bad but thanks for your support so far anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working again! I had Ubuntu running under VirtualBox and just copied all of the files from /etc/NetworkManager to my actual Ubuntu and it was working again!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the applet cannot comunicate with network-manager, the service that manages the network. The most likely cause is that it is not running or not installed.

If it is installed but not running, try:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

If it is not installed, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager network-manager-gnome
```

The gnome tools are likely already installed, but it never hurts.

Comment: I updated my question according to your advice

Answer (score 1):

As Javier pointed out here in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/148086/107321), a reason can be that `network-manager` is not running. That again can have reasons as discussed in askubuntu.com question ["network-manager does not start automatically"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252644).

The most likely reason is a network interface that is configured with autostart and DHCP in `/etc/network/interfaces`, but not connected at system startup. A symptom for that cause is a message "Waiting up to 60 seconds more for network configuration ..." at startup.