# network-manager do not start automatically

Tags: network-manager

How to auto start network-manager?

I installed ubuntu mini iso and ubuntu-gnome-desktop (without the install recommendations). So, I have the system working fine, except that the network manager do not automatically start. I even tried adding it to the gnome-session-properties (startup applications), but no luck.

I am using the following command to manually start it through terminal: sudo service network-manager start

I also get the message while booting saying that 'waiting for netwrok configuration' and then 'booting without full network configuration'.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had a left over entry for eth0 in /etc/network/interfaces which was configured to use DHCP, but since there was no ethernet plugged into eth0 DHCP could never succeed.

Check /etc/network/interfaces, comment out everything other than:

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

Then reboot and hopefully network-manager will start as expected.

Answer (score 1):

1)In /etc/ there should be some rc files or an rc.d, search around in them and try to figure out which services (Daemons) are starting up on boot.

2)Try the following:
I deleted all pid file in /var/run and all subfolders especially /var/run/dbus
I moved all data from /var/run to /run then deleted /var/run folder.
I made a symlink /run to /var/run.

3) Follow this article https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/811441 and look at #24. Although the version they are talking of is different from yours, the suggestion might help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this workaround of mine could help you. Note that it doesn't solve the root cause of this situation, it just makes things simple and functional.

First, execute this command:

```
sudo vim /etc/rc.local
```

Then, the content should look similar to this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#Sleeping a little might be necessary to let it catch up the boot. 
#However, for me, this sleep was a useless overhead.
#sleep 3 
service network-manager restart

exit 0
```