# How can I enable and keep wifi without restart networking service in ubuntu server?

Tags: 13.04, wireless, networking, server, 64-bit

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.04 x64 server, and I've been able to connect to my wi-fi network during the installation process. However, since I boot it, two messages appear (both "Waiting for network configuration..." and "Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...") and there is no way to connect with the router.

I've googled that issue, also I've opened the /etc/network/interfaces configuration file to review the settings, and in fact, both id and network password are saved properly. The only way to get it connected is using the commands

```
sudo service networking stop
sudo service networking start
```

or using

```
sudo service networking restart (it causes the same result).
```

So, the only way to solve this problem is restarting the service, but I suppose that there is an automatic way to do it. I've installed Ubuntu desktop 13.04 x64 in the same computer, it detects the network SSID immediatly, keeps the wi-fi settings and it connects to the router without any restarting or strange tweaking, so I've wondered why with the server edition it's difficult.

The best scenario is using a specific server OS because I need it to perform some web service and of course you know that is enough with a console access, to use SSH, ftp and so on.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I suspect there is a flaw in your /etc/network/interfaces file. Please edit your question to include it. Please disguise any passwords.

Comment: This might help http://askubuntu.com/questions/252644/network-manager-do-not-start-automatically